# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition NOT working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation, navigator

I've been using google API's for a while and there's an error that I've been facing continuously. I've implemented geolocation and my API doesn't work in chrome between around 9.00 am to 11.30 am IST giving an error that "network location provider at googleapis returned error 403". Although, Google API works fine in Mozilla, IE, Chrome for mobile. It only gives error in chrome for desktop between around 9.00 am to 11.30 am IST, which is not established pattern, as today 23/mar, it is not working even after 11:30 AM. Please someone suggest what should I do in this situation. I'm attaching a screenshot of the error below.

This is the function that I'v used, (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition) and this gives me an error.
[image]

Comment: I think better you could as this in Web Apps SE

Comment: Iam also facing the same issue. Found problem only with chrome.

Comment: I have same problem, only with chrome and only at certain times of the day

Answer (score 0):

403 error comes in case of

- Daily Limit Exceeded
- User Rate Limit Exceeded
- The user has not granted the app {appId} {verb} access to the file {fileId}
- get more errors info from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-  errors

To get detail information about the issue , try to print api response. it should be as below

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "domainPolicy",
        "message": "The domain administrators have disabled Drive apps."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The domain administrators have disabled Drive apps."
  }
}
```

Comment: How to examine this response? navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(cb, errcb) resolve errcb with only one arg: PositionError {code: 2, message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403."}